# How to install a program to the non-volatile memory on Windows CE?

Tags: installation, windows-ce, cab

I created a CAB setup for Windows CE using Visual Studio 2008. Everything was installed fine but all my files went to the volatile memory (*\Program Files*). Is there a way to install them to the non-volatile memory (*\Hard Disk\Program Files*)? I could write to the *\Hard Disk\Program Files* directly but I'm not sure whether this path is the same for all wince devices.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The path is definitely not the same.  It can be things like "Hard Disk" or "Storage Card" and een across devices, that folder name is often localized.  You have to create a custom installer DLL that will determine what the name of the non-volatile store is and then unpack the files to that location. A basic template for the DLL can be found here.

Comment: Thanks for the help. By the way, where can I get a name for the non-volatile store?